# Real time audio analysis Android

Tags: android, audio

I've got a rather complicated problem that I need to solve at work. It's pretty far out of my remit of "Android App Developer" - I would class it as a very specialized audio engineering problem.

I am tasked with developing an application, which needs to be able to stream either a local audio file or audio from streaming service apps such as, but not limited to, Spotify, to another device over Bluetooth.

In addition, the app needs to be able to estimate the BPM of the streamed audio (it is assumed all audio will be musical) and use this BPM value to control the playback speed of a lighting sequence.

This question is about how to estimate the BPM of the streamed music.

For the case where the audio file is local, I can think of some solutions for this, such as hardcoding the BPM into the app, in a map against the audio resources URL.

I have also investigated and experimented with "static" library (aubio) than can estimate BPM from an audio file, but not on the fly. It assumes .wav format. This won't be sufficient for what we are trying to achieve here.

However, given the requirement for streaming external audio from streaming service apps such as Spotify, a static analysis solution is pointless as the solution wouldn't work for the streaming service case, and the streaming service case solution will work for both cases.

Therefore, I have come to the conclusion that somehow, I need to on the fly analyze the streamed audio, perhaps with FFT or peak detection algorithms.

This question isn't about the actual BPM estimation algorithm itself (or the implementation details of how I would get there) and is about the basic starting point of such a solution:

How might I go about getting A) the raw bytes of streamed audio for both the local file case and the external streaming service app case and B) how might I process these bytes into a data structure representing the audio stream in a way amenable to running audio analysis algorithms on it.

I realize this is very open ended, quite vague question, but this is so far out of my comfort zone I've no idea how to even formulate a more coherent question.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by creating some separate, more tightly defined questions for the different pieces. For example, ask how to get access to the raw bytes when streaming local file, or streaming URL-sourced audio. Android has some nice support for streaming, including the ability to stream PCM, so I'd be pretty surprised if getting a hook for access to the byte stream were not possible.

Once you have a hooking point, to convert the bytes to "something useful" I'd look at using the audio format to tell you how to read the incoming bytes. The format should tell you how many channels (mono or stereo), the encoding (e.g., signed PCM is common, might be normalized floats), the number of bits per value (16 is common) and the order of the bytes (big-endian vs little endian).

I know that there are posts that will explain how to convert the raw audio bytes to PCM values based on this info, including some on stackoverflow. They should be reachable via search. I think signed normalized floats is the most common data representation used for processing audio signals.

Comment: Thanks Phil - looks like I've got a lot of learning to do.